# C : pipe does not work if I use multiple files

Tags: c, linux, pipe

I'm still new to pipes and I want to understand why this is not working.

Assuming I have the following :

**main.c** :

```
#include "macros.h"
#include "child_parent.h"

int main()
{
    if (pipe(pipefd) == -1)
    {
        perror("pipe");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    switch(fork())
    {
        case -1:
            perror("fork()");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

        case 0:
            return child();

        default:
            return parent();
    }
}
```

**child_parent.c :**

```
#include "macros.h"
#include "child_parent.h"

int child()
{
    char buf;
    close(pipefd[1]); // Close unused write end

    while(read(pipefd[0], &buf, 1) > 0)
        CHECK(write(STDOUT_FILENO, &buf,1),"write1()");

    CHECK(write(STDOUT_FILENO, "\n" , 1),"write2()");
    close(pipefd[0]);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int parent()
{
    const char *msg = "Hello world!\n";

    close(pipefd[0]); // Close unused read end
    CHECK(write(pipefd[1], msg, strlen(msg)),"write3()");
    close(pipefd[1]);

    wait(NULL);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**child_parent.h :**

```
#pragma once

static int pipefd[2];

int child();
int parent();
```

**macros.h**

```
#pragma once

#define CHECK(func, msg) do {       \
    if ( (func) == -1) {            \
        perror(msg);                \
     }                              \
    }while(0)                       \
```

So basically I just wanted to test the inter-process communication between anonymous pipes. When compiling the program, it throws the following error:

```
write3(): Bad file descriptor
```

Which means that the parent process couldn't write into the pipe.

But when writing the whole implementation in main.c, the communication will work correctly.

So it has to do with the static int pipefd[2] that is declared in child_parent.h.
What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Putting `static int pipefd[2];` in `client_parent.h` means you end up with a definition of `pipefd` in *each* translation unit.

Comment: I see, so I just have to define it in main.c globally without static and get it in child_parent.c using extern pipefd[2] ?

Comment: @Upgrade Yes, and trying as such should demonstrate that to you. The `extern` decl *can* be in the header, btw, so long as only one translation unit actually formally defines that pipe set (such as your main.c as you suggested).

Comment: @Upgrade You could make it `extern int pipefd[2];` in `child_parent.h` and define it in `child_parent.c`. That should keep it where it belongs.

Comment: One other tip: child() should not return.  As written, the child process calls exit(3), which triggers exit handling, including e.g. functions added with atexit(3). Instead of `return child();` I would write `_exit(child());`.